# Defining an operator

Tags: syntax, operators, pure-function

Let `s` be a positive integer and let `DifferenceDelta` be [this function](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DifferenceDelta.html) with `step = 1`. Define `DifferenceDelta^s` to be an operator that applies `DifferenceDelta` `s`-times to any function `f[x]`.

What *Mathematica* syntax will give me the result of `(1 + DifferenceDelta)^s f[x]`? It seems that *Mathematica* does not support operations with "pure" operators.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? `Nest[DifferenceDelta[#, i] + 1 &, f[i], s]`

Comment: Sorry, it should be `Nest[DifferenceDelta[#, i] + # &, f[i], s]` because `1` is a identity operator. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Imo, your description of the problem is not consistent with the fact that you find Anon's answer well fitted to your needs. The only thing that agrees is the expected result.

Comment: @Kuba Would you explain that further? You got me interested... what is the difference?

Comment: @Anon My interpretation is that OP wants to set some `UpValues` for `DifferenceDelta` so his notation can be interpreted as what your code performs. But that would be not the first time when I missed something so I'm not insisting :)

Comment: @Anon Do you agree? :)

Comment: @Kuba OK, now I understand. Yes, I considered this as well but at the end I figured the notation was not the main problem. Usually people who ask such questions already have the code and they're asking only for a new notation. But I see what you mean.

Comment: If you wish to apply `DifferenceDelta` a number of times `n`, isn't this already part of the definition of the function? The second argument is: `DifferenceDelta[f,{i,n}]` where `i` is the difference and `n` is the number of times to apply it.